# Looking for the best way to delete data on a sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have a sheet where I often delete the data on it and I have two methods to delete the data without the header.
I would like to know which of these two methods is the most efficient and quickest.

```
Private Sub test()
Dim lastrow As Long
'preventif is my sheet
lastrow = preventif.Cells(preventif.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).up
'Method N°1
preventif.Cells.range("A2:Y" & lastrow + 1).Delete  
'Method N°2
preventif.range("A2:Y" & preventif.Rows.count).Delete 

End Sub
```

Comment: show the relevant part of your code

Comment: i've edited the question

Comment: i want to count the filtered data et set them as source for my pivot table

Comment: Let’s say I have more than 20.000 rows of data? I’m dealing with lots of data on the sheet.

Comment: if you want to know what's faster, why don't you just measure ? (I just did, and it's the second one)